# Tailwind CSS v3 not applying after migrating from Bootstrap 5 on Angular 13

Tags: javascript, css, angular, tailwind-css, bootstrap-5

So I decided to migrate from Bootstrap 5 to Tailwind CSS 3. The steps that I took were npm uninstall bootstrap, remove dependencies from angular.json and install tailwindcss according to steps from https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/angular.

angular.json

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "river-valley-irregulars": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        },
        "@schematics/angular:application": {
          "strict": true
        }
      },
      "root": "projects/river-valley-irregulars",
      "sourceRoot": "projects/river-valley-irregulars/src",
      "prefix": "rvi",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/river-valley-irregulars",
            "index": "projects/river-valley-irregulars/src/index.html",
            "main": "projects/river-valley-irregulars/src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "projects/river-valley-irregulars/src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "projects/river-valley-irregulars/tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "projects/river-valley-irregulars/src/favicon.ico",
              "projects/river-valley-irregulars/src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "projects/river-valley-irregulars/src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "projects/river-valley-irregulars/src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "projects/river-valley-irregulars/src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "river-valley-irregulars:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "river-valley-irregulars:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "river-valley-irregulars:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "projects/river-valley-irregulars/src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "projects/river-valley-irregulars/src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "projects/river-valley-irregulars/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "projects/river-valley-irregulars/karma.conf.js",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "projects/river-valley-irregulars/src/favicon.ico",
              "projects/river-valley-irregulars/src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "projects/river-valley-irregulars/src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "river-valley-irregulars"
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "rvi",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "analyze": "ng build --stats-json && webpack-bundle-analyzer .dist/river-valley-irregulars/stats.json"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "~13.1.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.4.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~13.1.3",
    "@angular/cli": "~13.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~13.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.10.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.10.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "typescript": "~4.5.2",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^4.5.0"
  }
}
```

Did I miss any steps? Please help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are total 6 steps in docs for how to configure tailwindcss with angular ? Did you follow all steps ? including tailwind.config.ts file to adding @import inside style.css ?

Comment: Yes, and yes. I've "@import" inside the styles files. As for me, I'm using "styles.scss" -> "@ import "tailwindcss/base";
@ import "tailwindcss/components";
@ import "tailwindcss/utilities";"